# gulp-tslint @7.0.1 Cannot read property 'findConfiguration' of undefined

Tags: typescript, gulp, tslint

when I am trying to lint ts files using gulp-tslint I am facing some issue.

I got a npm warning as "gulp-tslint@7.0.1 requires a peer of tslint@>=4.0.0-dev but none was installed."

and when I create a linting task it throws error as "TypeError: Cannot read property 'findConfiguration' of undefined"

your help will be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you able to manually install `tslint`?  `npm install tslint@4.3.1 --save-dev`

Comment: Do you have configuration file in your solution as tslint.json and tsconfig.json?

Comment: yes, I have both the files

Answer (score 0):

The answer is right in the error:

> gulp-tslint@7.0.1 requires a peer of tslint@>=4.0.0-dev but none was installed

**What is the solution?**

```
npm install tslint --save-dev
```